# Show loading screen while waiting for NodeJS to Parse a json File

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I have a project where I need to make an angular http.post request to a nodeJS server which will parse a open dataset from  a URL and pass this as a json string of objects to angular. 
The problem with this event is that parsing the JSON from a open dataset and parsing it, handling it and so on... takes in a lot of time. But I need that data to fill in my website's content, or to use the functions in my website.

So I want to know is how to show a bootstrap `modal`which will either show a spinner OR it will just say "Loading Data" for as long as I don't receive the data in my angular. This way I will prevent users to be exploring my website while it's still empty because there is no data to work with yet.

---

NodeJS code for parsing:

```
app.post("/", function (req, res) {
    request("http://datasets.antwerpen.be/v1/bevolking/inkomensvolgenswoonplaatsperdistrict.json", function (error, response, body) {
        if (error || response.statusCode != 200)
            return (res.status(response.statusCode).end());
        var data = JSON.parse(body);
        res.json(data.inkomensvolgenswoonplaatsperdistrict);
    });

})
```

Angular request code:

```
app.controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.getAll = function () {
        $http.post(url + "/")
            .success(function (res) {
                console.log(res);
                $scope.All = res;
                angular.forEach(res, function (value, key) {
                    console.log(key + " : " + value);
                })
            });
    };

})
```

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: I want to create this modal as long as I don't have the response from node, how do I do this?

Comment: Show the modal when function is called , hide it when response is received. Suggest using `angular ui bootstrap` and get rid of `bootstrap.js`

Comment: yes but how do I do this? and does this angular ui bootstrap affect any changes made to far using the regular bootstrap?

Comment: in `$scope.getAll` before the `$http.post` open the modal. When `$http.post` returns, regardless of outcome, close the modal.

Comment: So bassicly call the modal on request and close it in the .success handling ? and how to I call the modal? got any short code perhaps?

Comment: @TomKustermans moved to an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `$scope.getAll` before the $http.post open then modal. When `$http.post` returns close the modal. This should be done in the event of both an error or success.

See the [angular-ui-bootstrap Modal docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) for implementation examples for integrating the bootstrap Modal into you angular app.

Comment: I got it working by calling it with a javascript function in the $scope.getAll thanks loads m8 ;)

Comment: Are you available for another question by any chance? :)

Comment: It's about collapse panels. I want to have only 1 collapse panel active at all time, so if any button would open a collapse panel, the other one should close. Is it clear what I am trying to do?

Comment: I really recommend using angular-ui-bootstrap for this, I know you weren't using it when you asked the original question but they have an entire Directive do this called [`Accordion`](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion). It supports, only having one item open at a time natively using the boolean attribute `close-others`

Comment: but this supports all other bootstrap code I have written so far, right? If so, could you enlighten me how to load in this module?

Comment: Just read the [getting started](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/getting_started) section of Angular UI Bootstrap. If my answer was helpful above, you should mark it as answer and upvote it so people who look at this question later know that this answered your question.

Comment: If I use the ui-bootstrap, can I delete all bootstrap files/links i have made in my html head tag?

Comment: No, you won't need to. This will just give you access to different directives implemented in angular so you don't have to build out the different Bootstrap components in HTML. You can continue to use the code you've already written and utilize the Angular UI Bootstrap Directives to make your life easier when wanting to use things like the Accordion or Modal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100520/discussion-between-tom-kustermans-and-peteb).